# redirecting based on referer using mod_rewrite ignoring the GET parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to restrict the access to a webpage with mod_rewrite, based on the referer.
The webpage's URL is
http://www.example.com/path/to/page.php
It is located on a Debian server in `/var/www/path/to/page.php`
I have a rewrite map `allowedReferers` containing a list of URLs

`allowedReferers`

> http://www.example.com/test/test1.php:white
>
> http://www.example.com/test/test2.php:white

I also have the following rewrite conditions/rules

Rewrite

```
Cond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${allowedReferers:%1|black} ^black$ [NC]
RewriteRule /* http://www.someotherplace.com [R,L]
```

So far this works perfectly well.

> http://www.example.com/test/test1.php
>
> http://www.example.com/test/test2.php

Can access the website, while

> http://www.example.com/test/test3.php

gets redirected to someotherplace.com.

My problem is that, in real life, my referers will contain GET parameters.
e.g.

> http://www.example.com/test/test1.php?id=245

My idea was to rewrite the first condition to something like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)\?.*$
```

or this

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)\?id=[0-9]*$
```

I've tested both regexes in Firefox' RegexTester and they behave as I want them to.
Applied to the following input

> http://www.example.com/test/test1.php?id=245

they return this for `$1`:

> http://www.example.com/test/test1.php

I expected that `%1` also contains the URL minus the GET parameters.
So that, leaving the rest of the rule unchanged:

```
RewriteCond ${allowedReferers:%1|black} ^black$ [NC]
RewriteRule /* http://www.someotherplace.com [R,L]
```

should result in the expected behavior:

> http://www.example.com/test/test1.php?id=234
>
> http://www.example.com/test/test2.php?id=222

can access the website, while

> http://www.example.com/test/test3.php?id=256

(or http://www.athirdplace.com/ etc.)

will be redirected to someotherplace.com

Unfortunately it does not behave as expected at all.
Having applied the change to the first condition suddenly every referer has access to the website.

As I wanted to see what actually is inside of `%1`, I came up with the following idea:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)\?id=[0-9]*$
RewriteCond ${allowedReferers:%1|black} ^black$ [NC]

RewriteRule /* %1 [R,L]
```

Assuming that refering to the page from

> http://www.example.com/test/test2.php?id=234

would redirect me to

> http://www.example.com/test/test2.php

Wrong assumption. It redirects me to

> http://www.example.com/var/www/path/to/

which is, as I mentioned in the beginning, the address of the page whose access is to be restricted.
And of course provokes a 404, as `/var/www/` is docroot.

Redirecting to `%1` was just a desperate attempt to debug my problem, so I do not need a solution to achieve this. What I'm looking for is a way to solve my original redirection problem.
Referers like these

> http://www.example.com/test/test1.php?id=234
>
> http://www.example.com/test/test2.php?id=222

(no matter which id is passed)

go to

> http://www.example.com/path/to/page.php

while everything else goes to

> http://www.someotherplace.com

Finally I would also appreciate any ideas how to debug `mod_rewrite`, especially ways to peek into stuff like `%{HTTP_REFERER}`, `%1`, `$1`, and the likes.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution how to (at least partially) debug mod_rewrite:

http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2007/09/05/a-couple-ways-to-debug-mod_rewrite

provides a very handy trick to output some of the values mod_rewrite is using.
I modified the example a little bit, to the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)\?id=[0-9]*$

RewriteRule (.*) /path/to/mod_rewrite_debugger.php?referer=%{HTTP_REFERER}&p1=%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

mod_rewrite_debugger.php just contains

```
echo "&lt;pre&gt;"; print_r($_GET); echo "&lt;/pre&gt;"
```

The output is:

```
[referer] => http://vfh143.beuth-hochschule.de/tests/moodle3.php?id=3

[p1] => http://vfh143.beuth-hochschule.de/tests/moodle3.php
```

Which shows that my original assumption was right.

Unfortunately the debugger doesn't work anymore when the second condition is applied:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)\?id=[0-9]*$

RewriteCond ${allowedReferers:%1|black} ^black$ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) /path/to/mod_rewrite_debugger.php?referer=%{HTTP_REFERER}&p1=%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

produces the following output:

```
[referer] => http://vfh143.beuth-hochschule.de/tests/moodle3.php?id=3

[p1] =>
```

Turns out that the rules suddenly worked as originally intended. The Problem solved itself.

Maybe this helps someone.